# Can't link IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service to IoTHub not found

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I just created an IoTHub with a Device Provisioning Service and I get an error when I try to link the two together.
The Azure portal sends me back

There was a problem updating your Device Provisioning Service to link to IoT hub. An unexpected error occurred while updating your Device Provisioning Service. Error message: Unable to find the IoThub `<my iothub>.azure-devices.net`. Check if the hub exists and the connection information is correct.

Is it an Azure problem or a configuration problem on my side?
Thank for your help

I try to link manually from the portal my DPS and my IoT Hub but it doesn't work. I follow the documentation about shared access policy configuration but mine is on "Allow"

Comment: I just tried linking by creating a new DPS and IotHub and it works fine. Can you share few more details to understand the issue better? Which region you are seeing this failure? Are you referring to [How to link and manage IoT hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-manage-linked-iot-hubs)?

Comment: created IOT device using [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-setup-auto-provision#create-an-iot-hub) and connected Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service (DPS) [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Tk02817.png) are trying to connect in another way.

Comment: Are using PowerShell or CLI to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where are located the issue. It's because my iothub was not accessible via public network.
I just change Terraform related setting and it was done.

Answer (score 0):

> I created [IOT device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/dps/linked-hub?view=azure-cli-latest) using [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-setup-auto-provision#create-an-iot-hub) and connected Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service (DPS). I got the same error and resolved it.
> Thanks to **Victoria Litvinova** for [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/src/azure-cli/azure/cli/command_modules/iot/_help.py)

### - In bash

[image]

- ***To check if the list of IOT Hub connected to DPS [bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/dps/linked-hub?view=azure-cli-latest).***

```
az iot dps linked-hub list --dps-name dpsname --resource-group resourcegroupname
```

[image]

- ***For linking dps existing with Iot hub in Bash***

```
 az iot dps linked-hub create --dps-name MyExampleDps --resource-group MyResourceGroup --connection-string "HostName=MyExampleHub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=user123" --location westus
```

[image]

[image]

***For updating Dps existing with IoT hub in Bash***

```
az iot dps linked-hub update --dps-name MyDps --resource-group MyResourceGroup --linked-hub MyLinkedHub.azure-devices.net --allocation-weight 10 --apply-allocation-policy True
```

[image]

### - In Powershell

[image]

- ***To check if the list of IOT Hub connected to DPS ***
- Poweshell

```
az iot dps linked-hub list --dps-name $dpsName --resource-group $resourceGroupName
```

**For linking dps with Iot hub**

- Poweshell

```
az iot dps linked-hub create --dps-name MyExampleDps --resource-group MyResourceGroup --connection-string "HostName=MyExampleHub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=XNBhoasdfhqRlgGnasdfhivtshcwh4bJwe7c0RIGuWsirW0=" --location westus
```

[image]

**For updating Dps with IoT hub**

- using PowerShell update the DPS

```
az iot dps linked-hub update --dps-name MyDps --resource-group MyResourceGroup --linked-hub MyLinkedHub.azure-devices.net --allocation-weight 10 --apply-allocation-policy True
Update linked IoT hub 'MyLinkedHub.azure-devices.net' in an Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service
```

[image]